# Change link background colour when link clicked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a basic jQuery Accordion. I'd like to change the background colour on a link if that link is clicked.

So if I click 'Dropdown 1', the background colour changes to red. How do I do this?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/4dm318nn/

```js
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.inline').find('.navtoggle').click(function(){

      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".sub-menu").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  });
```

```css
  .accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
  .sub-menu {display: none;}
  .sub-menu .sub-menu {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="medium-8 columns primary menu">
 <ul class="inline naked">
        <li class="primary-item"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress">Home</a></li>      
  <li id="menu-item-74" class="primary-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-74"><a href="#" class="navtoggle">Dropdown 1</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-76"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=45">Dropdown 2</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-77" class="sub-sub-menu menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=47">Test 1</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-78"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=49">Test 2</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add red color when clicked**

CSS

```css
  .accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
  .sub-menu {display: none;}
  .sub-menu .sub-menu {display: block;}
```

HTML

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<nav class="medium-8 columns primary menu">
    <ul class="inline naked">
        <li class="primary-item"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress">Home</a></li>                       
        <li id="menu-item-74" class="primary-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-74"><a href="#" class="navtoggle">Dropdown 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-76"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=45">Dropdown 2</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-77" class="sub-sub-menu menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=47">Test 1</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-78"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=49">Test 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('.inline').find('.navtoggle').click(function(){

  //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).css('background-color','red').next().slideToggle('fast');

  //Hide the other panels
  $(".sub-menu").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

});
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a Demo/Fiddle? I can't see the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

not sure this is what you want, but is

```
$(".inline.naked li").click(function(color){
   var bgColor = typeof x === "undefined" ? "red" : color;
   $(this).css("background-color", color);
});
```

what you want?

Comment: Sorry. Not exactly. It should be when a link is clicked.

Comment: right, I have realized it right before you commented and changed it

Comment: It is any link that has a sub-menu. So not just 'Dropdown 1'.

Comment: so remove the if and leave the $(this).css("background-color", "red") statement alone.